# Will external JDK/JRE affect the compile/run performance?

Tags: java, compilation

I have a SOHO NAS on my LAN that I'd like to use as a library for programming languages, so I don't have to install tons of languages on my computer. My idea is to have JRE/JDK 7, 8 and so on running on the NAS while I just have my IDE pointing to it when I need to compile and/or run something.

But I have a doubt, if I use this structure, will the compile/run use my computer or my NAS resources? I'd like it to use my computer resources as it's way more powerful than my NAS. My idea is to just have the NAS storing the various libraries, languages, etc that I use.

Comment: Why on earth would you do something like that? Don't you have space on your hard drive?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your description, the local machine's RAM, CPU, etc. would be used. You'd still have lesser performance, however, due to file access occurring across the network.

Comment: @Kayaman, I do have space, but I prefer to leave the machine as clean as possible to avoid issues. I need to use various programming languages and libraries and they end up "polluting" the machine, even causing some errors and inconsistency sometimes.